# MediaLibrary Delphi typecast error

Tags: delphi, firemonkey, delphi-10.1-berlin

I have a problem with the MediaLibrary on Delphi.

I make this code below on my main form:

```
unit uPrincipal;

interface

uses
  System.SysUtils, System.Types, System.UITypes, System.Classes, 
  System.Variants,FMX.Types, FMX.Controls, FMX.Forms, FMX.Graphics, 
  FMX.Dialogs,
  FMX.Controls.Presentation, FMX.MultiView, FMX.Objects, FMX.Layouts,
  FMX.StdCtrls, System.Actions, FMX.ActnList, FMX.StdActns,
  FMX.MediaLibrary.Actions, FMX.MediaLibrary, FMX.Platform, System.Messaging;

type
  TfmPrincipal = class(TForm)
    Layout1: TLayout;
    mvMenu: TMultiView;
    rctMenuPrincipal: TRectangle;
    rctMenuTop: TRectangle;
    rctMenuBody: TRectangle;
    rctOpHome: TRectangle;
    rctBodyPrincipal: TRectangle;
    tbPrincipal: TToolBar;
    StyleBook1: TStyleBook;
    sbMenu: TSpeedButton;
    sbPhoto: TSpeedButton;
    ActionList1: TActionList;
    TakePhotoFromLibraryAction1: TTakePhotoFromLibraryAction;
    Image1: TImage;
    TakePhotoFromCameraAction1: TTakePhotoFromCameraAction;
    procedure TakePhotoFromLibraryAction1DidFinishTaking(Image: TBitmap);
  private
    { Private declarations }
  public
    { Public declarations }
  end;

var
  fmPrincipal: TfmPrincipal;

implementation

{$R *.fmx}
{$R *.LgXhdpiPh.fmx ANDROID}
{$R *.NmXhdpiPh.fmx ANDROID}
{$R *.iPhone.fmx IOS}

uses uLogin, uTeste;

procedure TfmPrincipal.TakePhotoFromLibraryAction1DidFinishTaking(
  Image: TBitmap);
begin
  Image1.Bitmap.Assign(Image);
end;

end.
```

When I run this on my phone, I click on the SpeedButton, and I receive an "invalid class typecast" error message.

I have added `TakePhotoFromLibraryAction1` in the `TActionList`, and set it as the `Action` for the SpeedButton.

I don't know why I am getting this error.

Answer (score 2):

It's a bug in your version of Delphi.

One workaround is to use a `TButton` instead of a `TSpeedButton`.

Another workaround is to remove the `Action` assignment from the SpeedButton, and then use the button's `OnClick` event to call the action's `ExecuteTarget()`method, passing it a different control as the `Target` parameter.